# VBA syntax when file location does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this VBA syntax to open an input file from my active workbook:

```
Set wk = Workbooks.Open(datalink)
```

"datalink" here is a cell containing a link to the input file. In some cases, the data file doesn't exist so this syntax fails to open the link. How can I write a syntax that in those case, the macro still move on and ignore the error?

Thanks in advance. Excuse my very beginner question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Dir` function to see if it exists.

```
If Dir(datalink) = "" Then
  MsgBox datalink & " not found."
Else
  Set wk = Workbooks.Open(datalink)
End If
```